# Why does Time Machine estimate a 109GB backup size, but then need 235 GB?

Tags: time-machine

I'm running Time Machine on a new NAS. Until today, I used to run it on an USB drive. I am reusing the old job using the new 10.8 feature that allows me to add new backup targets.

When I configure the backup job in the system settings - there are some things like VMs that I want to exclude - Time Machine estimates the backup size to be 109 GB.

When I start the backup, however, it talks about 235 GB. I don't like this, as I don't want to litter the NAS with unnecessary data.

Is it normal that Time Machine shows such a huge difference between the System dialog, and the actual backup?

Comment: Did you have the USB drive plugged in at the time? Maybe Time Machine was going to copy over some of the older backups for you. If this was a laptop, it might be caused by local snapshots, but that difference seems far too big for that.

Answer (score 1):

This discrepancy is odd - most of the time when people see more than a 25 GB error, it's with Time Machine over-estimating the space that will be used rather than under-estimating. You might be on to something where there is abug in calculating things with multiple backup targets - I've not seen that configuration start to misbehave yet - so you might be one of the lucky few to see how things break under that setup.

If you can make this happen repeatedly, I'd submit a bug (or at least poke around) by running the `tmdiagnose` tool to collect data on the estimates and actualities.

Also, the [Backuploupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) tool is amazing at getting at space usage and estimate oddities when you use Time Machine. It's not able to catalog both destinations simultaneously yet - but seems to work well enough on Mountain Lion that I still use it regularly.