# Time Machine Backups taking too much space?

Tags: backup, time-machine, disk-space

Yesterday, I installed an external hard disk for my Time Machine — well, a 1.6Tb partition of a 2Tb hard disk. I am running a new iMac with 512Gb SSD. The internal drive is about half full.

After a day, I have about 5 backups, and I find that I only have 448Gb available.

I am still trying to get the other folder sizes (understandably, this is taking a long time), but the first backup folder is about 250Gb. At a rough estimate, this suggests that the subsequent backups are about the same size. At this rate, I will run out by tomorrow.

I understood that the Time Machine backups are sort of differential, and that subsequent backups are mostly links to the original backup files.

The question is: is the size, being mis-reported, or is that a correct estimate of the space used?

Answer (score 6):

I would probably do two things:

1. Let time machine run until it fills up the 1.6 TB and then see how long a windows you have. macOS will clean up the destination - purging old files as needed.
2. Use `tmutil compare` or a tool like [Backup Loupe](https://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) to check what is taking the space. Other tools do a lousy job of showing you actual space usage in time machine.

   - [Why does Time Machine estimate a 109GB backup size, but then need 235 GB?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73331/why-does-time-machine-estimate-a-109gb-backup-size-but-then-need-235-gb)
   - [Time Machine - List of Files that were backed up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68515/time-machine-list-of-files-that-were-backed-up)

Comment: Nice answer - I always think of Time Machine as simply "taking up all the space that's available" & make volume sizes appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @bmike. I’ll try out your suggestions and get back as soon as I have more info.

Comment: Sounds good @Manngo . A follow on question and link it here in a comment and I'll see it. Look for large database files - you'll want to exclude them and find another way to back them up or shard them (VMware and Parallels both have info on that for example)