# Time Machine - How can I backup only Documents folder

Tags: macos, time-machine

I'm trying to backup `Documents` folder only. Folder contains 10GB. Entire `User` folder is about 50GB.

When trying to exclude **all** folders (included hidden ones ), I get to 48GB of backup storage required.

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Some really smart people have been stumped by this, so I’m sure TM over counts in some cases. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363939/time-machine-backing-up-way-more-space-than-hard-drive-contains

Comment: It is usually recommended for your backup drive to be 3x the volume of the data you want to backup: that should include sufficient duplication for those files that change. Even a 250 Gb disk would give you 5x the size. So I'd suggest backing up more, rather than less.

Comment: Also, is it possible that you have a backup of an iPhone or iPad on your Mac? That's likely the source of the size difference. At worst, you could exclude the `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup` folder.

Comment: @benwiggy regarding size- it is not what I’ve asked. Regarding possible backups- all directories are marked off including hidden, and no subdirectories present below Documents

Answer (score 1):

The estimates are [often off to be conservative](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73331/why-does-time-machine-estimate-a-109gb-backup-size-but-then-need-235-gb), make sure enough space is there to not run out if the [estimate is not perfect](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57184/why-is-time-machine-over-stating-the-amount-of-data-that-needs-to-be-backed-up).  Just exclude every folder and allow a token empty one to back up. After several intervals, the estimate will be better and you can add documents back by removing it from the exclusion list.

Comment: I'm trying to backup to NAS, using WiFi. It would take forever....

Comment: Aah, I’ll remove that. My main comment stands, reduce your backup selection and incrementally relax it if you need to squeeze. Perhaps a different tool would be better to backup your data like arq or borg if you’re setting up servers and network shares. @Guy.D